# Sox batch process under Debian

Tags: linux, bash, batch-processing, sox

I want to resample a bunch of wav files that I got on a folder.

My script is this:

```
for f in *.wav; do sox “$f” -r 48000 “${f%%%.wav}.wav”; done
```

The console give me this error: "sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `“90.wav”': No such file or directory" and so on with the 300 files that are placed on that folder.

How can I batch processing right this files? Why is it giving me this error?

Thanks a lot!

**Solution:**

```
for i in *wav; do echo $i; sox $i -r 48000 ${i%%.wav}r.wav; done
```

Comment: Try this: for f in ./*.wav; ...

Comment: There seem to be 1 `%` too much, but if you write `"${f%%.wav}.wav"` or even `"${f%.wav}.wav"`, this become useless... You could'nt overwrite you file while you're reading it!

Comment: What's with the triple percent signs?  I've seen one and two, but not three.  Brief experimentation reveals that the third is used literally, at east in Bash.

Comment: @techno Yeah, it works by accident, by actually ending up with `09.wav.wav` as the output file, because the substitution didn't do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Summary: It is the quote symbols

The problem is with the double-quotes:

```
for f in *.wav; do sox “$f” -r 48000 “${f%%%.wav}.wav”; done
```

The double-quotes above are non-standard.  For them to be properly processed by the shell, the standard ASCII quote symbol must be used:

```
for f in ./*.wav; do sox "$f" -r 48000 "${f%%%.wav}.wav"; done
```

As an aside, note that `${f%%%.wav}` removes any occurrences of `%.wav` from the end of the input file name.  `${f%%%.wav}.wav` adds one `.wav` back on to the end after removing any `%.wav` suffixes.  You likely want something else here.

#### Verification

Using the bad quote characters, as per the question, observe the error message:

```
$ for f in *.wav; do sox “$f” -r 48000 “${f%%%.wav}.wav”; done
sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `“90.wav”': No such file or directory
```

Note the file name in the error message is shown with two-sets of quotes around the file name.  This is what you saw as per the error message that in the question.  The outer single-quotes are supplied by `sox`.  The inner double-quotes are the funny quote characters provided on the command line.  Because they are non-standard characters, the shell left them in place and passed them to the `sox` command.

While the file `90.wav` exists, no file by the name of `“90.wav”` exists.  Hence, the error.

#### Conclusion

Stick to standard ASCII characters for shell commands.

This issue can easily happen if the shell commands are typed in using a fancy word-processing editor that substitutes in typographically-pretty but non-standard characters.  As tripleee points out, it can also happen when copying-and-pasting from the websites with inappropriate typographical styling.

Comment: ... or copy/pasting from a blog which foolishly applies typographical styling to code.

Comment: @tripleee Excellent thought: I just added it to the answer.

Comment: I had a script that works fine for me with ImageMagick, not from a website. I had the script on my Drive on a text file. Thanks for your answer John.

Comment: @DaNoiseMan Did you try it again with plain ASCII double-quotes?  If you did and it didn't work, what error message did you receive?

Comment: This did the trick:

for i in *wav; do echo $i; sox $i -r 48000 ${i%%.wav}r.wav; done

Thanks again John!