# Sox batch conversion

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, audio, sox

I'm trying to convert 728 .raw files to 16khz .wav files by using the script given in the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264156/sox-batch-process-under-debian) but I'm receiving an error

> sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `./*.wav': No such file or
>   directory

script I'm using is

```
for i in ./*.raw; do sox "$i" -r 16000 "${i%%.wav}r.wav"; done
```

the script is in `convert.sh` and the raw files are in rawfiles folder. The file structure is like

`/Orginal/rawfiles/.rawfiles` and `/Orginal/convert.sh`

I have 728 files to convert .raw files to 16 bit 16khz mono wav files.
What modifications do I have to do in order to remove the error and convert the files?

Comment: Which folder are you running this script from? `*.wav` will look for files with `wav` extension and not `.raw` files

Comment: @Inian I'm sorry. That was a mistake. I corrected it. In is in `*.raw`

Answer (score 3):

The SOX code line that you are using is not at all for raw file conversion, check the [SOX full documentation](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) for more info.

Next is an explanation on: what is a raw file, followed by the correct code.

First you need to know that **A raw file is a headerless file**.

In order to convert raw files into wav, you need to recreate the file header, that consists of:

- Sample rate (44100, 16000, 8000, ...) [Hz]
- Sample size [bits]
- data encoding (floating-point, μ-law, ADPCM, signed-integer PCM)
- channels (usually: 1 mono or 2 stereo)

So, [as mentioned in this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059014/converting-raw-audio-data-to-wav-with-scripting), the format is:

```
sox -r 16000 -e unsigned -b 8 -c 1 <RAW_FILE> <TARGET_FILE>
```

This is for the specific case that your raw data is originated from a 16KHz sample rate with 8 bit per sample encoded with unsigned integer, and it is one channel.

Next, 
for the for loop, you can use any *for* script that works...
[So the answer from: tripleee, with this modification will work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48884679/sox-batch-conversion/48885701#48885701):

```
mkdir -p outputdir
for i in rawfiles/*.raw; do
    o=outputdir/${i#rawfiles/}
    sox -r 16000 -e unsigned -b 8 -c 1 "$i" "${o%.raw}.wav"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The script is looking in the current directory.  The error message looks like you simply have no files matching the wildcard in the current directory.

I guess you want

```
mkdir -p outputdir
for i in rawfiles/*.raw; do
    o=outputdir/${i#rawfiles/}
    sox "$i" -r 16000 "${o%.raw}.wav"
done
```

If you want the files in the current directory, obviously don't create or write to `outputdir`.

Comment: I'm getting an error `sox FAIL formats: bad input format for file`.Code inside for loop is this  `o = outputdir/${i}`      
 `sox "$i" -r 16000 "${o%.raw}.wav"`

Comment: The error seems unrelated to the code you posted; check the `sox` manual page. The spaces around the equals sign would cause a syntax error (unless you have a command named `o` which likes an equals sign as its first argument; the assignment is superfluous if you don't need to trim anything off the beginning of `$i` anyway).

Answer (score -1):

Here is the windows equvilant that may help you.
I had this same problem and could not find the solution via here or any other site. So I kicked and moaned and figured it out, you can convert it for use in linux shell "$", but here's the batch convert sox for 96hz 24bit to 48hz 16bit flac to flac. Of course, you can change this to whatever combination you want (i.e. 16b 44.1k).

Create a batch file, i.e: 24b-96hz to 16b-48hz-FLAC.bat

```
@break off
mkdir ".\FLACOUT\"
FOR %%F IN (".\*.flac") DO sox.exe "%%F" -S -b 16 -r 48k -C 8 ".\FLACOUT\%%~NF.flac"
```

It will take the *.flac files from your main directory and create a sub called FLACOUT (or whatever you rename it to), and put the newly downsampled files into that subdirectory with the same name and metadata.